# Shutdown Jenkins slave from Master

Tags: windows-server-2012, jenkins, slave

A Jenkins 1.651 master and slave have been installed on a Windows Server 2012. 
I need a way to kill the slave from the master (I already have a job that start the slave).
Could you please give me any advice on the best way to proceed?